# Togglz Yml/Yaml Configuration for My SpringBoot Not working

Tags: yaml, togglz, spring-boot-starter

Trying to create Feature Toggles using Togglz.
Made below configurations/code in my Application,

```
bootstrap.yml:
     togglz:
       enabled: true
       features:
         FEATURE_ONE: true
```

Feature Enum Class:

```
public enum AppFeatures implements Feature {

    @Label("FEATURE_ONE") FEATURE_ONE;

        public boolean isActive() {
        return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
    }
}
```

> My Requirement:

I need to do like this, if FEATURE_ONE is configured true in yml file, then if condition, else, else has to execute..

```
if(AppFeatures.FEATURE_ONE.isActive()){}else{}
```

but my expectation not happening. Though I have given true in yml file, AppFeatures.FEATURE_ONE.isActive() is not true, help/guide me to figure out where am making mistake.

**Note am using, togglz 2.4.1 final and springboot 1.3.3, I need enabling/disabling should be done in yml only, not in enum class.**